# Difficulty in importing a module using Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, python-3.5

```
import QuantLib as ql
```

The above module import works perfectly fine when I invoke **ipython** instance from the commandline on windows and am able to perform computations.

Whereas in Pycharm 2016.1 the above invocation always fails. I set the paths under Pycharm to the right location of QuantLib.

Everytime I try to debug in PyCharm, I get

```
"File C:\Anaconda\Lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 193  MAXINT = 2L**31-1 message
```

I am running python 3.5 on windows. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`xmlrpclib` is a part of `Python 2.x` Standard library. On Python 3, you have to call `xmlrpc`.

You can either replace `xmlrpclib` with `xmlrpc` or switch Python Version to 2.x